# ansible in masterless mode git task fails while git clone works on remote server

Tags: git, github, ssh, ansible

I am using Ansible to clone a repository on a remote server :

This command works on the remote server: `git clone git@github.com:ansible/ansible-examples.git`

This task, however, fails:

```
- name: clone git repo
      git: repo=git@github.com:ansible/ansible-examples.git 
           dest=/root/ansible-examples
           clone=yes
```

With the following output:

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git ls-remote '' -h refs/heads/HEAD", "failed": true, "msg": "Permission denied
>   (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access
>   rights\nand the repository exists.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "Permission
>   denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access
>   rights\nand the repository exists.\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines":
>   []}

I have a similar situation (ssh and cloning works with CLI but not the task) with a private git repo that I can clone on the remote server (using ssh forwarding) but fails with the same task.

I also have the following in my `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
transport = ssh

# deprecation_warnings = False # In case it matters get the following [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Instead of sudo/sudo_user, use become/become_user and make sure become_method is 'sudo' (default).

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

*Note:* I am using ansible from my OSX laptop, to an Ubuntu remote. The version is `ansible 2.1.0.0`.

How do I make this task clone the git repository ?

**Edit**

Unsure what that means, but the following does not work either (and the same in the console works) :

```
- name: clone git repo
  shell:  if [[ ! -d /root/ansible-examples ]] ; then echo "CLONING" && git clone git@github.com:ansible/ansible-examples.git /root/ansible-examples ; else echo "already there" ; fi
  args:
    chdir: /root/
    creates: /root/ansible-examples/
```

**Another attempt:**

```
shell: git clone git@github.com:ansible/ansible-examples.git /root/ansible-examples
```

> FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "git clone
>   git@github.com:ansible/ansible-examples.git /root/ansible-examples",
>   "delta": "0:00:00.693890", "end": "2016-06-08 20:57:47.505574",
>   "failed": true, "rc": 128, "start": "2016-06-08 20:57:46.811684",
>   "stderr": "Cloning into '/root/ansible-examples'...\nPermission denied
>   (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access
>   rights\nand the repository exists.", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [],
>   "warnings": ["Consider using git module rather than running git"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I did not have the same ssh user in CLI and ansible. Editing the host file fixed it: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html

Specifically the `ansible_user` and `ansible_connection`.

Comment: Maybe this might help someone else: The global use of `become: yes` is also a common pitfall which leads to such an issue. Directly after login this would switch to root user and thus the key forwarding wouldn't stick to the new session.

Comment: This helped me after my ssh git clone randomly started failing. Thanks!